# Facebook php api in Ajax facebox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to load some php fql calls in to an ajax facebox (its like lightbox), i include a file with the following code in, but it does not work without the redirect ($my_url), is there any way to make the code ignore the redirect? Or do i need to use the javascript sdk from facebook?

```
$app_id = 'APP ID';
$app_secret = 'APP SECRET';
$my_url = 'LINK HERE';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

$bruger = "me()";

//auth user
if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
    . '&code=' . $code;

// response is of the format "access_token=AAAC..."
$access_token = substr(file_get_contents($token_url), 13);
```

Comment: You can not “include” the login dialog anywhere in your page – it has to be displayed from facebook.com directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)? I highly recommend moving away from depreciated FQL as once you get to grips with the new API it is very easy to use

Once you have set up `$facebook` you can then just make API calls with `$facebook->api('/query');`

I'm not 100% sure what information you are trying to retrieve from your question however but I have put together a Lightbox / Facebook myself, even using tag data to pick people out of the picture so feel free to provide more detail and I will try to provide a more comprehensive answer

EDIT:
In order to build queries and test data returned you can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET) and construct the query you want to test against your own Facebook Application

> I'm trying to fetch friendlist

After you've setup `$facebook` then you can retrieve your friends by using

```
$fb_friends = $facebook->api("/me?fields=friends");
```

Next:

> 50 latest tagged photos and likes

To retrieve the latest 50 tagged photos and likes you'll need to do:

```
$fb_photos = $facebook->api("/me?fields=photos.limit(50)");
$fb_likes = $facebook->api("/me?fields=likes.limit(50)");

// I should mention that each time api() is called, the server makes a HTTPS request to Facebook, so it is worth condensing api queries to reduce load time:
$fb_data = $facebook->api("/me?fields=photos.limit(50),likes.limit(50)");

$fb_photos = $fb_data['photos'];
$fb_likes = $fb_data['likes'];
```

If you want the latest 50 of photos **and** likes chronologically sorted, you can `array_merge()` the two arrays and use a subval sort function for created_time, then just take the first 50.

> I'm going to insert all the basic info into mysql (stuff like name, facebook id, email ect.) I'm going to use the fb id inserted into myslq, to view the friendlist, likes and photos

Right then, when you user logs on you will need to request extended permissions from them to access data like photos, likes and friends. When your user logs into facebook with the link you provide to them on your website, you need to call

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'read_stream,user_likes,user_photos,friends_photos,user_friends'));`
```

The scope is defined by the [permissions stated here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions)

Once you have been granted access to that information by the user you can retrieve profile information with `$user = $facebook->api("/me");` and store the facebook ID, name etc in your database.

To [get a better look at the data you'll be handing for photos](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?photos.limit%2850%29) then make sure that you click **Get access token** at the top of the page and grant permission to access photos and likes

Any more questions feel free to ask and I will provide more detail, hope that helps mate!

Comment: I'm trying to fetch friendlist, 50 latest tagged photos and likes. I'm going to insert all the basic info into mysql (stuff like name, facebook id, email ect.) I'm going to use the fb id inserted into myslq, to view the friendlist, likes and photos.

Comment: Please check the above :)

Comment: Works great thanks.. But when i click the ajax link, it doesn't include any of the php (the facebook stuff), since it's in another document (test.php). What do? And how do i turn 'off' some of the outputs, i dont really need likes, comments ect on the photos, since it's really to load.

Comment: You can specify the data that facebook returns in your api query like so: `$facebook->api("/me?fields=photos.limit(50).fields(images,picture,created_time) ");` You can test your queries in the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dphotos.limit(50).fields(images%2Cpicture%2Ccreated_time))